# disabling sidebar on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a click function which displays a sign-up form with a semi-transparent black background. Everything worked fine, except that I couldn't find a way to match the height of black background with whole height of the page.

I decided to add a CSS property "`body{overflow:none;}`" to the JavaScript function to stop users from scrolling down while the form is visible.

I tried it these ways:

1. `document.body.style.overflow="none";`
2. `$('body').css('overflow:none');`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.body.style.overflow=` is fine as a plain-JS way of doing it, but there's no such value as `none`. You might mean `hidden`.

Also, it is not (normally) the `<body>` element that owns the main browser scrollbar, but `<html>` (`document.documentElement`). Except when you're using IE and Quirks Mode. You don't want to use Quirks Mode.

Comment: yeha, $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); << works for me. Thanks for the kind support guys. Much appreciated (:

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery the syntax is:

```
 $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

To set the CSS property. [This page](http://api.jquery.com/css/) gives more details.

Comment: Im not sure why its still not working, heres the code 
<script>
$('a.GreenButtonBG').click(function(){

$('form#contactForm').show(); //works perfect
$('#mask').show().fadeTo('', 0.7); // no problems
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast'); // all fine
$("#contact").validationEngine() //works

$('body').css('overflow', 'none'); //has no effect

return false;
});
</script>

Comment: See bobince's answer for correct CSS syntax. I updated my answer accordingly.